# General approach to construct a basis for a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I know there are already threads, which discuss the construction of a basis for a specific vector space. But in general, if I am given a vector space and am asked to construct a basis for that vector space, how do I proceed?

For example, I am asked to construct a basis for \begin{pmatrix}x_{1}\\x_{2}\\x_{3}\\x_{4} \end{pmatrix}

with $x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}, x_{4} \in \Bbb R$ . The problem I am working on already gives me two vectors of a basis. These are:
$$\begin{pmatrix}2\\3\\-1\\5\end{pmatrix}  and  \begin{pmatrix}1\\3\\-1\\5\end{pmatrix}$$ So how do I approach finding two other vectors ( I know the basis consists of 4 elements since I already have seen the solution) that would complement the two vectors that are already given, so that all these vectors form a basis? I know how to check for linear independency. But how do I find vectors so that the span of these vectors equals $\Bbb R_{4}$ (all vectors with 4 rows and 1 column with components $\in \Bbb R$.

Comment: Use the Gram-Schimdt process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look  the following points:

1. a set containing $ n $ independent  vectors in a $ n$ dimensional vector space is a basis of that vector space.

Now for your problem  $dim( R^4)=4$   so you are to construct a linearly independent set of vectors containing 4 vectors  ( two vectors  are given , two are to be determined), then use my result 1.

Now consider the third vector $(0,0,1,0)$

Look at the  combination

$ (0,0,1,0)=a ( 2,3,-1,5) + b (1, 3,-1,5) $

and equating the coefficient you would get  $ a=0, b=0 $

Which shows that  {(2,3,-1,5),(1,3,-1,5),(0,0,1,0)}
is linear independent.

Now consider the fourth vector  $(0,0,0,1)$
Look at the combination

$(0,0,01)= a( 2,3,-1,5) +b (1,3,-1,5)+c(0,0,1,0)$

Equating both sides and solving you will get $ a=0,b=0,c=0$

Which implies   {(2,3,-1,5),(1,3,-1,5),(0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,1)} is linearly independent.

So we get the desired  independent set containing 4 vectors and  using result we get the desired basis.
Since  the chosing such vectors is not unique, so such vector vary from person to person.

Comment: "A set containing  independent vectors in a  dimensional vector space is a basis of that vector space." That sentence was the key for me to understand the process. We had that theorem in our class as well, however I must have forgotten it. Thanks !

Comment: Was there a particular reason for you to choose (0,0,1,0) and (0,0,0,1)?

Comment: No,look at my last line.it is the choice  of the person. Since it is easy to choose the standard basis so some people choose it got ease of calculation.